# sec.gov API call works in Windows PowerShell 5.1 but not in PowerShell 7.9.3

Tags: powershell

## Windows PowerShell 5.1

Running on Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001318605.json" -UserAgent 'ABC user@abc.com'
```

Result:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm> $result


cik                               : 1318605
entityType                        : operating
sic                               : 3711
sicDescription                    : Motor Vehicles & Passenger Car Bodies
insiderTransactionForOwnerExists  : 0
insiderTransactionForIssuerExists : 1
name                              : Tesla, Inc.
tickers                           : {TSLA}
exchanges                         : {Nasdaq}
ein                               : 912197729
description                       :
website                           :
investorWebsite                   :
category                          : Large accelerated filer
fiscalYearEnd                     : 1231
stateOfIncorporation              : DE
stateOfIncorporationDescription   : DE
addresses                         : @{mailing=; business=}
phone                             : 650-681-5000
flags                             :
formerNames                       : {@{name=TESLA MOTORS INC; from=2005-02-17T00:00:00.000Z; to=2017-01-27T00:00:00.000Z}}
filings                           : @{recent=; files=System.Object[]}
```

## PowerShell 7.9.3

Running on PowerShell 7.9.3:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001318605.json" -UserAgent 'ABC user@abc.com'
```

Result:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: The format of value 'user@abc.com' is invalid.
```

## Notes

Technically speaking, when making an API call to sec.gov, you're suppose to replace this:

'ABC user@abc.com'

With your company name instead of `ABC` followed by your email address. You can supply your own values.

## Question

Is there a way to get this call to work in PowerShell 7.9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this issue by adding the `-SkipHeaderValidation` parameter to your call:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001318605.json" -UserAgent 'ABC user@abc.com' -SkipHeaderValidation
```

This by-passes the cmdlet's header validation (where it considers your UA string to be invalid), and sends the request anyway.  Get more details here: [Skipping Header Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#example-7-skipping-header-validation)